# Mongodb query constructor to take raw query string Java

Tags: spring, mongodb-java

I am trying to come up with a concept to take a query string and have it passed into something like this via a query object:

```
returnList = mongoTemplateTracking.find(query,TrackingData.class, COLLECTION_NAME);
```

I've been looking at the constructors of both the Query and Criteria classes to see if they could take a raw string such as:

```
 "ID" : "32399a"
```

Instead of building up the Criteria object via Criteria.where().is() etc..

I have seen the method

```
protected <T> List<T> doFind(String collectionName,
                 com.mongodb.DBObject query,
                 com.mongodb.DBObject fields,
                 Class<T> entityClass)
```

However as I am autowiring the `mongoTemplateTracking` into my class I cannot access this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB query language ("MQL") is easily expressed in JSON form.  So if you have a string expression like:

```
String s = "{\"$or\": [ {\"name\": \"buzz\"}, {\"age\": {\"$lt\": 20 }} ] }";
```

then you can easily parse it with this util:

```
import com.mongodb.util.JSON;
DBObject query = (DBObject) JSON.parse(s);
yourCollection.find(query);
```

Take a look at [In Java, is there a way to write a string literal without having to escape quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034186/in-java-is-there-a-way-to-write-a-string-literal-without-having-to-escape-quote) to make the escaping of quotes in long query expressions a little easier.

Answer (score 4):

JSON.parse(json) was deprecated. use this code:

```
String s = "{\"$or\": [ {\"name\": \"buzz\"}, {\"age\": {\"$lt\": 20 }} ] }";
Bson bson =  BasicDBObject.parse( json );
collection.find(bson);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using raw query like this: `"{\"$or\": [ {\"name\": \"buzz\"}, {\"age\": {\"$lt\": 20 }} ] }"`

**this is the implementation part:**

```
String queryString= "{\"$or\": [ {\"name\": \"buzz\"}, {\"age\": {\"$lt\": 20 }} ] }";
BasicQuery basicQuery = new BasicQuery(queryString);
mongoTemplate.find(basicQuery, TrackingData.class, COLLECTION_NAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case, you're using Spring Boot Data.

```java
mongoTemplate.find(new BasicQuery("{salary: {$gt: 50, $lt: 100}, name: {$regex: '^A', $options: ''}}", TestDocument.class);
```